Is there a Python f-string equivalent of C++’s std::quoted?
In C++, the std::quoted stream manipulator produces a quoted and escaped version of a string:
std::string dirPath = "C:\\Documents\\Oval Office Recordings\\Launch Codes.txt";

std::cout << dirPath << endl; // C:\Documents\Oval Office Recordings\Launch Codes.txt

std::cout << std::quoted(dirPath) << endl; // "C:\\Documents\\Oval Office Recordings\\Launch Codes.txt"

Is there a direct Python f-string equivalent to std::quoted? By “direct,” I mean “built into Python” rather than “you can roll your own version.”
(Context: I have a C++ Quine I use when teaching a theory course that uses std::quoted to keep things simple. I’d like to port it to Python with as little invasive surgery as possible.)

std::quoted if for quoting strings for CSV file. Do you want to quote the string for CSV file, or you want to quote the string in python for C++ program, or do you want to quote the string in python for python? By "for C++", I mean the result is a string which can be compiled using a C++ compiler, and by "for python", I mean the resul tis a string which can be interpreted by python. All these are different. Python has import csv whole module, you could make a reader and write one field to it and get result.

You probably want repr.
>>> print("C:\\Foo\\Bar")
C:\Foo\Bar
>>> print(repr("C:\\Foo\\Bar"))
'C:\\Foo\\Bar'

Note that single quotes are legal string delimiters in Python. For a quine, you can use %r as a format string for repr; one of the more popular quines is this one-liner:
_='_=%r;print(_%%_)';print(_%_)
For an f-string, or format string, you can use the !r modifier:
>>> s = 'C:\\Foo\\Bar'
>>> print(f"{s!r}")
'C:\\Foo\\Bar'
>>> _='_={!r};print(_.format(_))';print(_.format(_))
_='_={!r};print(_.format(_))';print(_.format(_))


Yep, that looks like what I was looking for. I'm aware there are very short Python quines, but my goal in teaching a course is to show an intuitive way to write one, which means my quine is a lot longer. :-)

If you need shell-escaped name you might use shlex.quote which is part of standard library.
import shlex
simple = shlex.quote("simple")
with_space = shlex.quote("name with space")
print(simple)  # simple
print(with_space)  # 'name with space'

Observe quotes are added where they are required.
